# Bukkit Coding - Kick message with color codes set in config.yml

Tags: java, bukkit

So I have a plugin im making where they get kicked with a message. I want that message to be in color that is set in the config.yml. heres my code:

```
        }
    if (l == 2) {
        settings.getData().set("" + target.getName() + "", null);
        settings.saveData();
        target.kickPlayer(this.getConfig().getString("BanMessage"));
        target.setBanned(true);
        Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.RED + target.getName() + " " + "Has been tempbanned for 25 Minutes by " + sender.getName() + "" + "(3/3)");           
        Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                        target.setBanned(false);
                }
        }, 1500 * 20);
        return true;


    }
```

Heres my config.yml:

```
BanMessage: You have been temp banned for 25 Minutes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes()`:

```
String kickMessage = plugin.getConfig().getString("BanMessage");
kickMessage = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', kickMessage);
target.kickPlayer(kickMessage);
target.setBanned(true);
```

You can use [these color codes](http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/4/4c/Colors.png?version=34a0f56789a95326e1f7d82047b12232) in your configuration file.

So, putting in **&6You have been banned for &4Spamming** Will give you **ChatColor.GOLD + "You have been banned for " + ChatColor.DARK_RED + " Spamming"**

and if you would like to make it so they get that same message whenever they join if they're banned, you can use:

```
@EventHandler
public void playerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){
  if(myMethodToCheckIfAPlayerIsTempBanned(e.getPlayer()){
    String msg = myMethodToGetPlayersBanMessage(e.getPlayer());
    e.getPlayer().kickPlayer(msg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
String kickMessage = this.getConfig().getString("BanMessage");
kickMessage.replaceAll("(?i)&([a-f0-9])", "\u00A7$1");
target.kickPlayer(kickMessage);
target.setBanned(true);
```

Then, you should be able to use [these color codes](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Classic_server_protocol#Color_Codes) in your config.

ex.

**BanMessage: &3You &0have been banned &1for &425 &3minutes**

will display as

```
You have been temp banned for 25 Minutes
```